# GCE - Switch ON and OFF a VM from API request

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm figuring out if there is a way to switch ON and OFF an instance on Google Compute Engine directly by API (hosted on app engine with PHP).

I've found this documentation: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start

But can't understand if this documentation is what really i need or not :/

EDIT:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google-ComputeSample/0.1');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');

$service = new Google_Service_Compute($client);



// Project ID for this request.
$project = 'my-project'; 

// The name of the zone for this request.
$zone = 'europe-west3-c';  

// Name of the instance resource to start.
$instance = 'name-instance';  

$response = $service->instances->start($project, $zone, $instance);


print_r($response)
```

Get this error:
*Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information'*

I'm trying to run this code from localhost, i think this is the problem.

If i run this code from an app engine inside my project, i suppose it will work.
But the google-php-client folder for the APIs has > 10000 files inside, so I can't push it on an app engine versione and try it :/

Comment: The first step is to actually implement something and then ask a question when you have a problem. You have tagged `PHP`. Did you review the PHP SDK? Do you want to use raw HTTP requests? Have you considered how you will authenticate and authorize your requests? There are examples on the Internet on how to start a GCE instance in several languages. The document link that you included in your question has a PHP example. Did you study it? If yes, what is wrong with starting with that example?

Answer (score 1):

The document that you cite is correct for what you want to achieve, so using that API call you will start a VM instance and with the method instances.stop you will stop them. The examples for PHP are in the same document, to start [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start#examples_1) and to stop [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop#examples_1). I hope this information helps.